# Complex select statement

Tags: php, sql

I have 4 tables

```
Tbl_Items: 
   Asset Id, 
   Asset_name, 
   Workshop,
   PAT_PASS
```

(workshop, and PAT_PASS are either YES or NO. Workshop = YES and PAT_PASS = NO means this item is not available for hire..)

```
Tbl_Project_details:
   Project_id, 
   Project_start_date, 
   project_end_date

TBL_Project_items:
   Project_id, 
   Asset_id,
   Start_date,
   End_date
```

I need to do a select statement that allows me to show all the items in tbl_Items EXCEPT:

```
1) Those that are already in use on another project on the dates that I need them.
2) Are in the workshop. (Workshop = YES)
3) Are not PAT Tested (PAT_PASS = NO)
```

So far I have started with a simple statement like this:

```
$post_project_id = "13-1309.01";  //this is just an example number..

$sql = 
"SELECT * FROM Project_details 
Where Project_id = '$post_project_id' ";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$hire_start_date = $row['Start_date']; // we find out our projects start date
$hire_end_date = $row['End_date'];     // we find out our projects end date
}  

$result=mysql_query("SELECT Items.Asset_id, Items.Name  
FROM 
Items,Project_items 
WHERE
Project_details.Start_date < '$hire_start_date' 
AND 
Project_details.End_date > '$hire_end_date'") 
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
// fill up an option box with the results
}
```

Even this basic script doesn't seem to work! This is the first time I have tried selecting from multiple tables, so this is a steep learning curve!

Thanks!

Comment: A join or subquery is what you need at first glance, but what you need most of all is to _quit using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension_

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: There is no error message, so the actual statement is correct. I think the logic is wrong?

Comment: @AndyJones: It's not because you're not seeing any errors that there aren't any, change your php.ini setting to `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` and set display_errors to 1, to ensure that _all_ warnings and errors actually make it to the screen

Comment: 1. That first `while`-loop only assings $hire_start_date and $hire_end_date, but does nothing  with them. Perhaps everything that follows should be done within this while-loop...
 2. As suggested: use MSQLi (or PDO) and possibly data-binding...

Comment: For better answers, post the CREATE TABLE statements for each table.

Comment: @MBaas The $hire_start_date and $hire_end date variables are used in the next SELECT statement...

Comment: Yes, but if you do that next SELECT after the WHILE, it means you only do it for the last record...

Answer (score 0):

`$StartDate` and `$EndDate` are your date constraints:

```
 SELECT ITEM.asset_id,
        ITEM.asset_name,
        ITEM.workshop,
        ITEM.pat_pass
   FROM Tbl_Items ITEM
        LEFT JOIN Tbl_Project_Items PJITEM
           ON PJITEM.asset_id = ITEM.asset_id
           AND PJITEM.start_date BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
           OR PJITEM.end_date BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
   WHERE ITEM.workshop = 'no'
     AND ITEM.pat_pass = 'yes' 
     AND PJITEM.asset_id IS NULL
```

Who's Pat?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl_Items AS i WHERE
```

this should matches your (1.) condition: "take only those records, which with that select dont have any occurences":

```
0 = (
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TBL_Project_items AS pi
WHERE i.Asset_Id = pi.Asset_Id
AND Start_date < $hire_start_date
AND End_date > $hire_end_date
)
```

workshop condition (2.):

```
AND WORKSHOP != "YES"
```

pat tested condition (3):

```
AND PAT_PASS != "NO"
```

Comment: Do I need to do:
 **  2 = (AND WORKSHOP !="YES")  **
At the moment I have it all in one statement. It currently just selects everything from tbl_Items regardless of whether the conditions are met.

Answer (score -1):

One problem:

```
WHERE
Project_details.Start_date < '$hire_start_date' 
AND 
Project_details.End_date > '$hire_end_date'")
```

The columns "Start_date" and "End_date" aren't in the "Project_details" table. In that table, those columns seem to be named "Project_start_date" and "Project_end_date".